# Cakephp System-wide Search Function

Tags: cakephp, search

I am looking to implement a search function into my system that allows system-wide search that can search through every single model. Is that possible?

I have tried CakeDC Search plugin but it somehow only allows me to search in the particular model that I add the search function into. Also, it seems to be limited to the search fields that I add in the view and I have to keep adding those search fields to enable search for them. What I am looking for is something with just one search box and able to retrieve information from all over the system (eg. Google's basic search with just one search field).

would be great that someone can point me in the right direction or even provide instructions on how to do so as I am fairly new with Cake.

I am using PHPMyAdmin for the database and the latest version of CakePHP. Please do let me know if you need further information as I am not sure what I need to include here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/cakephp_search_plugin

The plugin allows you to attach the behavior to any model you want, and specifiy the table fields that it should take data from to create a search index. (basically when ever you save some data against the model, it runs through all the fields you specify it to look through, creates a data array to save, and saves the search data in its own table, ready to be searched on).

I would suggest giving this a go as it sounds like what you are after. The documentation provies detailed instructions on setting things up.

Hope it helps

Pete

Comment: thanks for that. I did try this search plugin but it doesn't work properly for me. But i'll give it another go. Thanks!